# Is this function positive?

Tags: integration, hilbert-spaces

I was wondering if:
$$\int_0^1x(t)\int_0^tx(s)ds\ dt$$
is positive for a general $x\in L_2[0,1]$ . Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By Fubini's theorem, the integral equals
$$ I=\int_{0\leq s\leq t\leq 1}x(s)x(t)\,dsdt. $$
By symmetry, 
$$ I=\int_{0\leq t\leq s\leq 1}x(s)x(t)\,dsdt. $$
Adding the two equations,
$$ 2I = \int_{0\leq s\leq t\leq 1}x(s)x(t)\,dsdt+\int_{0\leq t\leq s\leq 1}x(s)x(t)\,dsdt, $$
whence
$$ 2I = \int_{0\leq s,t\leq 1} x(s)x(t)\,dsdt. $$
By Fubini's theorem again,
$$ 2I = \left(\int_0^1 x(s)\,ds\right)\left(\int_0^1 x(t)\,dt\right) =  \left(\int_0^1 x(r)\,dr\right)^2.$$
The right hand side is nonnegative, hence so is $I$.

Comment: I am convinced and this sounds good for me. If anybody thinks that this is not true please let me know. Thanks @GH at MO

Comment: @HasanhasanHasan: As long as $x(t)$ is real valued, this is exactly how I was going to prove this.